# Conditional Order by multiple columns Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, conditional-statements

I have a table consisting of authors, few authors have both Bio and Image, few have only image, few have only bio, and few have neither..
bio and image are stored in different columns, 
I want to sort my query result (order by ) in such a way that authors that have both bio and image should come first, those which have images only should come secondary, those having bio should come in third order, and those with neither should come last.

How to write such a query..

Comment: I think you need to make 4 queries and use __UNION__ to join the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using CASE but it didn't work as per my liking, got a simpler solution to work.

```
Select * from mytable order by Condition1 Desc, condition2 desc, condition3 desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE` in order by so the authors with both bio and image will be listed first the authors with image then authors with only having bio and then the rest ones

```
select *
from table
order by case when bio is not null and image is not null then 3 
when image is not null then 2
when bio is not null then 1
else 0 end desc
```

Answer (score 0):

For multiple conditional ORDER BY statements:

```
ORDER BY CASE category WHEN 0 THEN concat(cName,', ',bName) END DESC,
         CASE category WHEN 1 THEN concat(aName,', ',bName,', ',cName) END DESC,
         CASE category WHEN 2 THEN concat(bName,', ',aName,', ',cName) END DESC
```